# Unable to get the information using wget using session ID

Tags: wget, cookies, session

I have been using Wget to pull the warranty information from my website using the following command.

```
wget -q -O getinfo.tmp "http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/warrantyLookup.do?type=$TYPE&serial=$SERIAL&country=897&iws=off"
```

Now IBM has changed the URL and provided with the dynamic session ID

The new URL, `http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/wlup`
stopped working some time ago when IBM changed the site to use dynamic session IDs.  I would love to be able to do this again, so if you know someone that can tell me how to do it, I would be extremely grateful.

You can use your machine type and serial to get the information or I can provide the sample data. Thank you very much for all your support and knowledge.